# How to hide the sender address in Outlook when sending mail from Java (MailMessageHelper)?

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have a mail utility written in Java, that sends out mail to outlook users.

```
private static final String _FROM = "noreply+example@example.com";
private static final String _SENDER_NAME = "Example Person";
MimeMessage mimeMessage = sender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true,"UTF-8");
messageHelper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_FROM, _SENDER_NAME));
messageHelper.setTo(InternetAddress.parse(addressList));
messageHelper.setCc(InternetAddress.parse(ccAddress)[0]);
messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
messageHelper.setText(content,true);
if(bodyImageName!=null && bodyImageSource!=null) {
    messageHelper.addInline(bodyImageName, bodyImageSource, "image/png");
}

sender.send(mimeMessage);
```

Now the message gets delivered to outlook but when I open the mail, both the name as well as the email address is shown -

```
Example Person <noreply+example@example.com>
```

How to show only Name and not the email address along with it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what mail server you're using.

Most public mail server will insist on a valid From header.

If you're using your own mail server, you might be able to configure it to allow you to "fake" the From header and include one with no address or no valid address.